# I am making a post request through laravel-vue on the browser and I am getting a 401, but it works on postman with the exact headers & paramaters

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js

this is the function that is triggered once the form button is clicked

```
      add_book: function(){
          axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/books', {
            headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer' this.token,
            },
            params: {
                'name': this.name,
                'description': this.description,
                'publication_year': this.publication_year,
            }

            }).then((response => {
                if (response.status == 201){
                    this.name = "";
                    this.description = "";
                    this.publication_year = "";
                    console.log('a new book is added');
                }
            })).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
        });
        console.log(this.name);
      }
  }
```

and this is the vs_code thunder client (an extension that works like postman) request.

enter image description here [post request on vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9pxJ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi9yN.png)

Comment: `'Authorization': 'Bearer this.token',` ... you are literally passing the token as `'this.token'`?

Comment: Probably should be `'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but in the actual code I am hardcoding the token so its 'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV....,' I just switched it here in the question with 'this .token', anyway I am 100% sure that there are no typos or syntactical error, because if I remove the word 'post' and instead write 'get', the endpoint with get request works.